# Score Calculation In Hang Man:Java code

Tags: java

I am writing a code for Hang Man game in Java.But I cannot write a proper code or find a way to calculate users' score and printing it at the users' end command with 0:stop.Here are the score calculation rules;

Score is computed as number of letters of the word  minus number of letters currently displayed.
Here “table “  score is 5-4=1 as when the user make a guess there are 4 letters already displayed.

If the user guess is not correct score is 0
If the man’s figure is completed before a guess, the score is 0

Each play of the game bu the same user is a session, the same word cannot be held by computer.
If “table” is held as a “things” it can bot be held by computer again n the same session.

When the user press 0 in the main mene, the session ends.

### Toptal number of plays, how many times correctly guessed , and total score of the user is displaid to the screen.

Also,i have a problem to prevent duplicate in random selected words array

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CEVIK_CAGATAY{
    public static char[] star;
        public static void main (String args[])
        {   
            char game[];
            int category;
            int correct=0;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            Random r = new Random();
            int totalplay=0;
            int totalscore=0;
            String man[] = new String[7];
            man[2] = " --\n o |\n/  |\n   |\n_____\n";
            man[3] = " --\n o |\n/| |\n   |\n_____\n";
            man[4] = " --\n o |\n/|\\|\n   |\n_____\n";
            man[5] = " --\n o |\n/|\\|\n/  |\n_____\n";
            man[6] = " --\n o |\n/|\\|\n/ \\|\n_____\n";
            String arr[]={"serhat","cagatay","begum","emre","berk","ali","veli","istanbul",
            "ankara","mersin","izmir","antalya","new york","samsun","kedi","kopek",
            "kus","ayi","bocek","karinca","manda","masa","pencil","bag","clock","televison","book","glass"};
            int arr1 []={6,7 };


            System.out.println("0 To Stop,1 to Continue");
            category=input.nextInt();



            while(category!=0){


            System.out.println("0 To STop,1 to Continue"); 








        String word = arr[r.nextInt(arr.length)];
            for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
                if(arr[i]==word){
                    int letterlength=arr1[i];
                }
                //letterlength-existedlength=guessremain;


            }
            int count = word.length();
            char[] CharArr=word.toCharArray(); 
            char[] star = word.toCharArray();
        for(int i=0;i<star.length;i++)
        {
            star[i] = '*';
            System.out.print(star[i]);

        }


        for (int i=1; i<=5; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf ("\nGuess a Letter:");
            char letter= input.next().charAt(0);

            for (int j=0;j<CharArr.length; j++)
            {
                if(letter == star[j])
                {
                    System.out.println("this word already exist");
                }
                else
        {
                    if(letter==CharArr[j])
                    {
                        star[j]=letter;
                        i--;
                        System.out.printf("CORRECT GUESS!\n");
                        correct++;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.print(star);
            switch(i+0)
            {
                    case 1: System.err.printf("Strike 1\n");
                    System.out.println(man[2]);
                        break;
                    case 2: System.err.printf("Strike 2\n");
                    System.out.println(man[3]);
                        break;
                    case 3: System.err.printf("Strike 3\n");
                    System.out.println(man[4]);
                    break;
                    case 4: System.err.printf("Strike 4\n");
                    System.out.println(man[5]);
                    break;
                    case 5: System.err.printf("Strike5\n");


                        System.err.printf("You're out!!! The word is Not_Matched\n");
                        System.out.println(man[6]);
                        break;
            }   


            System.out.printf("\n");
            if((new String(word)).equals(new String(star))) 
            {
                System.err.printf("Winner Winner\n");
                break;
            }
        }
        totalplay++;
        totalscore+=correct;
        System.out.println("CONTINUE 1,STOP 0");
        category=input.nextInt();
        if(category==0) {
            System.out.println(totalplay);
            System.out.println(totalscore);
        }

    }

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the following for loop.  It serves no purpose except to throw an Array Index Out of Bounds error.  Your program runs without it.  Be sure to practice best practices for language as well (such as camelCase for naming variables).  It makes your code easier for humans to understand.

```
for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
    if(arr[i]==word){
        int letterlength=arr1[i];
    }
    //letterlength-existedlength=guessremain;
}
```

Comment: can you also answer my question to calculate total score of users?